# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 33.1 GiB for an array with shape (192, 384, 60265) and data type float64

Tags: python, numpy, memory, netcdf, python-xarray

I have a large NetCDF data set (192 latitudes, 382 longitudes, and 60265 time steps, each with some float values) and would like to copy it to store in the copy the results of an complex calculation.

I tried the function `data.copy(deep=True)` and `data.load()`, but the data set is too big to load it into the memory. For this reason I am now looking for another variant.

This is how the code looks like:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import sys


def doit(data: xr.DataArray) -> xr.DataArray:
    result = data.copy(deep=True).load() # this fails since I cannot load 31GB into memory
    result = result.transpose("lat", "lon", "time")
    len_lat, len_lon = len(data.lat), len(data.lon)

    x = np.zeros(60265) # i.e., length of `data.time`
    for lat in range(len_lat):
        for lon in range(len_lon):
            # some complex calculation ... 
            # minimal example:
            result[lat,lon,:] = x 

    # some more stuff ...
    return result


def main() -> None:
    ds = xr.open_dataset("some_large_dataset.nc")["some_variable"]

    result = doit(data=ds)
    # ... some more stuff
    result.to_dataset(name='result').to_netcdf('result.nc')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    sys.exit(0)
```

If I do not use `copy(deep=True)` before the assignment, the following error occurs during `result[lat,lon,:] = x`:

```bash
NotImplementedError: Lazy item assignment with the vectorized indexer is not yet implemented. Load your data first by .load() or compute().
```

Also, copying the large dataset outside of python and then loading it requires at least a `load()` to be going to specific locations in the dataset.

I also tried using dask, but it is a requirement that data set that are passed to the real computation function which executes the loop does not use chunked data.

What other possibilities have I overlooked?

Here is the full code: [python-cmethods/blob/master/cmethods/CMethods.py#L145-L192](https://github.com/btschwertfeger/python-cmethods/blob/master/cmethods/CMethods.py#L145-L192)

### Edit - applied chunks as suggested by Nick ODell:

I now load the data set with chunks, so that one time series is represented by one chunk each. The assignment in the loop now runs without problems and loading into memory with `load()` is no longer necessary:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import sys


def doit(ds: xr.DataArray) -> xr.DataArray:
    x = ds.copy(deep=True).transpose("lat", "lon", "time")
    x[0,0,:] = np.zeros(10950)
    return x


def doit2(ds: xr.DataArray) -> xr.DataArray:
    result = ds.copy(deep=True).transpose("lat", "lon", "time")
    
    x = np.zeros(len(ds.time))
    len_lat = len(ds.lat)
    len_lon = len(ds.lon)
    
    for lat in range(len_lat):
        for lon in range(len_lon):
            result[lat, lon] = x
    return result


def main() -> None:
    ds = xr.open_dataset("dataset.nc", chunks={"time": 60265})['variable']

    result1 = doit(ds=ds)
    result1[0,0].load()               # this works and the values are np.zeros(60265)

    result2 = doit2(ds=ds)            # this works now
    result2.load()                    # RecursionError
    result2[0,0].load()               # RecursionError
    result2.to_dataset(name="result") # ok
    result2.to_netcdf("result.nc")    # RecursionError


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    sys.exit(0)
```

But now I get the error `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object` when I want to load or save the dataset or access certain elements.

I have found out that it is due to the number of iterations in the `for`-loop, because when I reduce the number of iterations, this error no longer occurs at some point. But I need the iteration over all locations/time series - how else can I solve this?

Comment: You have to change the algorithm   Only you know what your algorithm needs.  The code implies that the locations are independent of each other.  In that case, you could certainly do one row at a time or one column at a time. Or, you could decimate the time values.  The bottom line is you can't process the whole array as a unit.

Comment: It is a matter of iterating over all spatial dimensions and replacing each time series of the respective grid cell with an adjusted time series.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.  Does each location stand alone?  Is each one processed without using data from adjacent locations?  If so, then it's easy.

Comment: The locations/grid cells are independent. To compute the result for a specific location, only the time series of the respective location in the `data` data set is needed.

Comment: You can't modify just one part of an xarray and write it back to the file. This is a limitation of xarray: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/1117

Comment: `but it is a requirement that data set that are passed to the real computation function which executes the loop does not use chunked data.` Could you chunk the data so that one chunk contains all years for one lat/lon point?

Comment: @NickODell Okay I will try to change the requirements and chunk the data. I will respond when I have new results. Thank you!